# PostgreSQL where concat similar to MySQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I'm using the following query on my MySQL database:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) = 'John Doe'
```

I also have a PostgreSQL 8.4 database and i tried running the same query on that but get error that it does not recognise the CONCAT function.

Any ideas how I can achieve the same query on my postgresql ?

Thanks

Comment: Version 8.4, are you sure? Last patch was released over 7 years ago...

Answer (score 2):

8.4 is ridiculously obsolete and should not be used.

`concat` was not implemented until 9.1 (which is also very obsolete and also should not be used)

You can use the `||` operator, but keep in mind that they handle NULL values differently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use postgres' concatenation operator `||`:

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name || ' ' || last_name = 'John Doe'
```

Although you may find the following to be better suited for your condition to avoid doing expensive concatenations:

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE (first_name, last_name) = ('John', 'Doe')
```

Comment: Note that `||` isn't "*Postgres' concatenation operator*". It's the one specified in the SQL standard. However `concat()` (in current Postgres versions) behaves a bit differently compared to `||` when it comes to `NULL` values. So this isn't 100% identical